# boot.scr rebuild in buildroot

Tags: linux, u-boot, buildroot

Is there a way to rebuild boot.scr script without cleaning entire project?
I removed old boot.scr script and don't know how to genegrate new one (only `make clean` helps)

Variable BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_UBOOT_TOOLS_BOOT_SCRIPT_SOURCE is set.

`make uboot-dirclean uboot-tools-dirclean` didn't help.

I found that the mkimage script that creates boot.scr is called from the uboot-tools install rule, but even if I clear uboot-tools boot.scr no longer generates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dirclean host-uboot-tools it will rebuild your script. The reason is that mkimage (which generates the script) is called in the HOST_UBOOT_TOOLS_INSTALL_CMDS function in the uboot-tools.mk file.

As your personal script is in your external buildroot directory and you will probably want to iterate writing and testing it quickly you will want to make it every time. There is a way to do this each time you run make. No cleaning of anything is required. The post image script is the key.

For example, create your post-image.sh script and specify it in your defconfig file.

```
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_IMAGE_SCRIPT="$(BR2_EXTERNAL)/board/RK3308/post-image.sh"
```

In that post-iamge.sh script, run the command to generate your boot script, here is an example :

```
# Generate the uboot script
$ubootName/tools/mkimage -C none -A arm -T script -d $BR2_EXTERNAL_RK3308_PATH/board/RK3308/boot.cmd $BINARIES_DIR/boot.scr
```

Each time you run make, the boot.scr will be regenerated.

If you want to see all of this in context, [here is an external buildroot repo for the rk3308 chipset](https://github.com/flatmax/buildroot.rk3308).

This is the [post-image.sh file](https://github.com/flatmax/buildroot.rk3308/blob/master/board/RK3308/post-image.sh#L56).

This is [the definition of that file in the defonconfig file](https://github.com/flatmax/buildroot.rk3308/blob/master/configs/rockpis_defconfig).

Comment: Yes, I have my own post-image.sh script and I can run mkimage from there. This is a fine workaround, but I thought if there was an “official” way to generate a boot script, why not use it? I wonder why uboot-tools-dirclean doesn't force the script to be generated again?

Comment: Yes, true, you need to rm the host-uboot-tools directory. It is probably in the host-uboot-tools directory because it is something which happens on the host and not on the embedded system. I've updated my answer to include this information.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is correct, but there is easier way. The boot.scr is compiled by `host-uboot-tools`, not `uboot-tools`, thus you just need to execute this:

```
make host-uboot-tools-rebuild
```

Answer (score 1):

U-Boot provides the tool mkimage. In Debian based distributions it is in package u-boot-tools. Given that you have a file boot.txt with your script commands you can create boot.scr with

```
mkimage -T script -n 'My fancy title' -d boot.txt boot.scr
```